# Data leakage with keras train/test split

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I’m trying to build a very basic cnn to do multiclass image classification and getting a little stuck on one of the first steps of splitting the data! Following a youtube tutorial I initially created a dataset using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory() then split it into train/valid/test using .skip() and .take(). While the model worked great I noticed that the test set changed each time I used it (even if I only had 1 batch). My understanding is that doing this method, every time you use all the data, it reshuffles and redraws all of the samples. So, 1. Is this then a source of data leakage? In that as you train the CNN, at each epoch it redraws the samples and hence the model has already seen the test set?

As a result I decided to try creating a separate directory for test data that I don’t touch and just doing the train/validation split. Now, from reading online I realised I could just do this using validation_split keyword… However, that brings up the second question where if I do the split using validation split (Method 1 below) I only get validation accuracy up to about 0.5 during training, whereas if I do the skip(), take() method (Method 2) I can get up to 0.95… I’m clearly doing something different with these two methods but can’t see it. Could anyone explain what it is? And which method is better?

```
## METHOD 1 ##

validation_split = 0.2

train1 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
              train_dir,
              validation_split = validation_split,
              subset = "training",
              seed = RANDOM_STATE)

val1 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
              train_dir,
              validation_split = validation_split,
              subset = "validation",
              seed = RANDOM_STATE)

train1 = train1.map(lambda x,y: (x/255.,y))
val1 = val1.map(lambda x,y: (x/255.,y))
```

```
## METHOD 2
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_dir)

# Scale the pixel data to between 0 and 1
data = data.map(lambda x,y: (x/255.,y))
          
# Split into train, validation and test samples
n_batchs = len(data)
train_size = int(n_batchs*0.8)
val_size = int(n_batchs*0.2)

# if rounding causes sizes to be less than amount of data, add spare data to the training set
total_size = train_size+val_size
if total_size < n_batchs:
  train_size += n_batchs - total_size

train2 = data.take(train_size)
val2 = data.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: To avoid splitting the data differently each time you execute the code, you set the `seed` to a static value. Thereby, the random step becomes deterministic, and the data split will stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

In Method 2, you load the complete dataset with `image_dataset_from_directory` without setting `shuffle`. The [default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory#args) for `shuffle` is `True`. So each time you load the dataset, the images get randomly drawn, and then you split it into train/val. In this case you have a dataset leakage, as sometimes images are in train and sometimes they are in in val. This is bad and explains the high validation accuracy in Method 2, as the model had already seen these images in training.

You can avoid this in Method 2 if you either set a fixed seed, or you set shuffle to `False` and shuffle train and val separately.
Personally, I like Method 1 better, as you have 2 different datasets from the start, where you can apply different transformations if you want. Or shuffle only the training set, but not the val set for example. You could also load this in only 1 call:

```py
train1, val1 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    validation_split = validation_split,
    subset = "both",
    seed = RANDOM_STATE)
```

This way, you can be 100% sure to use the same dir, seed and val_split value for both train and val datasets.

Comment: ahhhh of course! It's the same reason I was having trouble with the test set originally. Thank you very much for the explanation. and thank you for the top about doing it in one call, didn't know that!